# Iterator as map value goes wrong

Tags: c++, address-sanitizer

Had a long time out of C++, thanks a lot!

Here's a simple LRU cache demo, I was intending to use `std::list<std::pair<int, int>>::iterator` to track data items inside the `std::list`, but it seems somethings goes wrong so `-fsanitizer` tells me `heap-use-after-free` warning.

```
class SimpleLRU {
 public:
  SimpleLRU(int cap) : cap_(cap) {}

  int get(int key) {
    auto it = cache_.find(key);
    if (it != cache_.end()) {
      int val = it->second->second;  <--- line 13
      list_.erase(it->second);
      list_.emplace_front(key, val);
      cache_.emplace(key, list_.begin());
      return val;
    }
    return -1;
  }

  void put(int key, int value) {
    auto it = cache_.find(key);
    if (it != cache_.end()) {
      list_.erase(it->second);
    } else if (cache_.size() == cap_) {
      cache_.erase(list_.back().first);
      list_.pop_back();
    }
    list_.emplace_front(key, value);
    cache_.emplace(key, list_.begin());
  }

 private:
  int cap_;
  std::list<std::pair<int, int>> list_;
  std::unordered_map<int, std::list<std::pair<int, int>>::iterator> cache_;
};
```

> error

```
==1903037==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: heap-use-after-free on address 0x60300000eff4 at pc 0x56488c0f9ff2 bp 0x7ffebf9a0ba0 sp 0x7ffebf9a0b98
READ of size 4 at 0x60300000eff4 thread T0
    #0 0x56488c0f9ff1 in SimpleLRU::get(int) test.cc:13
```

Comment: Can you simplify the code a bit for us

Comment: Please provide a `main` function that uses this class that duplicates the error.

Comment: I am looking at the method put(). It seems that when you reach the maximum size for cache you erase from cache but from the list as well, by calling pop back. Is this how lru cache works?

Comment: @Cristi The idea is that the key being accessed is removed from the middle of the list, and moved to the front. So elements in the list are arranged from most recently accessed in the front, to least recently accessed in the back. If the list is about to exceed the size cap, the entry from the back - the one accessed the longest time ago - is expunged to make room.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `SimpleLRU::get`, since `key` is already present in `cache_`, the call `cache_.emplace(key, list_.begin())` is a no-op - it does not replace the existing value with the new value. As a result, `cache_` ends up holding invalidated iterators. Make it

```
it->second = list_.begin();
```

---

Similar problem in `SimpleLRU::put`, only there you don't always have an iterator to an existing map element handy. Dealing with this issue is left as an exercise for the reader.